# ASP MVC Include into view foreign key class which is not mandatory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am new at MVC ASP, so to learn more I am making application on my own. It's working with EF of course, and database. The strange thing however, happens when I am trying to list all rows from table which has optional (null) foreign key (zero-to-many relationship). There is a class "Attribute" (based on table) which has column that is foreign key to table "unit", but that column in database is optional (null). Class is defined like this (reduced version):

```
public class Attribute
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string shortname { get; set; }
    public string longname { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "DataType")]
   [Required]
    public int datatypeid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("datatypeid")]
    public virtual PIMObjects.Helpers.DataType DataType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Uom")]
    public int uomid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("uomid")]
    public virtual Uom Uom { get; set; }
}
```

The other foreign key DataType is mandatory, and while that was the only FK index view which listed rows from this table showed all the rows from database correctly. This was the Index controller:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PIMContext context = new PIMContext();
        IQueryable<PIMObjects.Attribute> attributes = context.attributes.Include(a => a.DataType);
        return View(attributes.ToList());
    }
```

When I added non required UOM (unit) foreign key and added this to controller Index:

```
attributes = attributes.Include(a => a.Uom);
```

it just shows rows that have value for this field uomid. The other rows are not shown.
For now, in database there are two Attribute rows in table, one has uom, the other has null in uom column. It shows only the row which has the value.

What am I missing here?
btw this is the part that should show this field in index.cshtml

```
    <td>
        @if (item.Uom != null)
        { 
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Uom.unitname)
        }
    </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't try it out by myself right now but I would say you need to change the type of uomid from int to nullable int ("int?").